# An Issue of Copy Constructor

Tags: java, class, oop, copy-constructor

I have created a class of Robot with two properties: direction(It is just a string E,A,S,N) and location (an array of 4 integers that keep the location on both directions). The class has main constructor:

```
public Robot (int east, int north, int west, int south, int direction) {
this.direction = direction%4 ;
location = new int[4] ;
int[] location = {east,north,west,south} ; }
```

And a copy constructor:

```
Robot( Robot copy ) {
    direction = copy.direction ;
    location = copy.location ;
  }
```

Also it has methods but I want to show these two methods: move() and setDirection().

```
public void move() {
    location[direction]++ ;
  }

public void setDirection( int direction ) {
    this.direction = direction ;
  }
```

I created a Robot object and equalize it to a new object, also use another new object with using copy constructor:

```
  Robot terminator = new Robot(0,0,0,0,1) ;
  Robot b = terminator ;
  Robot a = new Robot(terminator) ;
```

Here is the problem, when I use move() method for terminator, a or b, both the location of others changes but when I use setDirection for terminator, a's doesn't change but b changes. Also when I use the same with a, none of b and terminator's direction changes. So, what is the difference? Why the move() method implemented on terminator affects the copy but when using setDirection() it doesn't?

```
System.out.println(terminator) ;
System.out.println(a) ;
System.out.println(b) ;

terminator.setDirection(2);
a.setDirection(3) ;
terminator.move() ;

System.out.println(terminator) ;
System.out.println(a) ;
System.out.println(b) ;
```

Output:

```
Location[0, 0, 0, 0]Direction N
Location[0, 0, 0, 0]Direction N
Location[0, 0, 0, 0]Direction N
Location[0, 0, 1, 0]Direction W
Location[0, 0, 1, 0]Direction S
Location[0, 0, 1, 0]Direction W
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your constructor:

```
Robot( Robot copy ) {
   direction = copy.direction ; 
   location = copy.location ;
}
```

You're doing shallow copy here.

Your `direction` is a primitive type, hence your copied `Robot` gains a copy of the original `Robot` direction value. They do not have same reference to `direction` variable

Meanwhile, your `location` is an array, hence your copied `Robot` gains a reference to the original `Robot` location. Both `Robot` have same `location` array. Change to one affect the another.

If you want to separate two `Robot` instance, you must do a `deep copy` the array `location`.

Instead of:

```
location = copy.location;
```

Do:

```
location = Arrays.copyOf(copy.location, copy.location.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Both `Robot` instances hold a reference to the same location `int[]`. You need to create a new array when creating a new `Robot` instance, e.g., using [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-):

```
Robot( Robot copy ) {
    direction = copy.direction ;
    location = Arrays.copy(copy.location, copy.location.length);
    // Here ---^
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I got it